# Codeigniter passing "Name/Name" as one parameter in a url

Tags: codeigniter

```
class Barcode extends CI_Controller 
{

    function index($barcode, $text='', $format="PNG", $quality=100, $width=160, $height=80, $type=1)

}
```

I have the following function and I want to pass the following in the URL:

http://localhost/index.php/barcode/index/1/Test%2FTest/PNG/100/256/80/1

But I get a 404 when trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to get all the parts of the GET request via `$this->uri->segment('{n}')` first?

I might be wrong, but I don't think the way you are doing it is right. If I was to code this I would do the following:

```
function index()  
{
    $barcode = $this->uri->segment('3');  
    $text    = $this->uri->segment('4');  
    $format  = $this->uri->segment('5');  
    $quality = $this->uri->segment('6');  
    $width   = $this->uri->segment('7');  
    $height  = $this->uri->segment('8');  
    $type    = $this->uri->segment('9');  

    // continue with your code  
}
```

Comment: The way he's doing it is fine. See also CI's [`uri_to_assoc()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) and PHP's [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php). It's an issue with the encoded slash, for me I get a *server* 404 (not a CI one). I'm not sure why, something to do with `.htaccess`?